# Alternative to BlockingQueue for inter-thread communication for producer-consumer type of problems

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, producer-consumer, message-passing

What are good concurrency paradigms and tooling to problems where items are `produced` at a high rate, `processed` concurrently and `consumed` sequentially in the same program? Without loss of data and without infinite memory.

I'm hoping for something that is more composable and reusable than, write your own using `Executors` and `BlockingQueue`.

Comment: If you're looking for a framework, maybe https://akka.io/?

Comment: "without infinite memory"- are they consumed faster than they are produced? (otherwise obv. your queues can grow indefinitely.)

Comment: Anyway, you can use executors only; the concurrent processing is done with an executor with N threads, and the sequential part can be done with a single-threaded executor. (no need to use blocking queue directly). Maybe have a look at guava's listenable futures?

Comment: @MickMnemonic, I wouldn't recommend plain old Akka actors since there is no back-pressure and at-most delivery is the default guarantee. Akka Streams on the other hand are reactive but the learning curve is steep!